# Math/economics problem: how do I create the most profit with limited budget and stowage capacity?

Tags: optimization, economics

For context: I am playing a game where you're supposed to transport goods with your ship to make money. Different goods have different purchase costs and profit margins. This made me figure I can come up with a formula of some sort to find out the most profitable stowage plan.

Given that there is a limited budget **b** and a limited stowage capacity **c**
and three cargo types:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c} 
 & \text{Cost} & \text{Revenue} \\ \hline
\text{x} & 50 & 200 \\ \hline
\text{y} & 250 & 500 \\ \hline
\text{z} & 600 & 1000 \\ 
\end{array}$$

When there is no limited stowage capacity (**b** is finite and **c** is infinite) it makes sense to buy and sell **x**, as it has the highest profit margin. However when there is no limited budget (**b** is infinite and **c** is finite), it makes sense to transport **z**, as the value density of the goods rise and **c** of **z** holds more value than **c** of **x**.

The problem arises when both **b** and **c** are (relatively) low. How do you calculate the highest profit, when there are 3 variables to play with?

Comment: I would say it is just a constrained optimation problem. $\textrm{max} \ \ 150x+250y+400z,$ $\textrm{s.t.} \ \ 50x+250y+600z\leq b, x+y+z\leq c$